# NodeJS idle operation during performance tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, jmeter, performance-testing

Relative newbie to nodejs here trying to figure out a performance issue in a newly built application.

I am running a performance test on my node 0.12.7 app and I find the server hanging intermittently. It needs a restart upon reaching that state. After confirming there is no memory leak (the process heap does not exceed 500 MB whereas the default max-heap size is 1.4GB I understand), we moved to checking CPU profile. I have used [this snippet of code](https://gist.github.com/danielkhan/9cfa77b97bc7ba0a3220) with a dependency on v8-profiler to get regular profiles

Here is one of the charts that we encountered from jmeter (although the server didn't hang) [image: Jmeter graph of requests]

We plotted flame graphs in Chrome by loading the CPU profiles. I was expecting to find the JS stuck somewhere at this point, but I find that exactly in that time range, the node server is idle for a long time. Could anyone help me understand what could be the probable causes for the server to stay idle while being bombarded with client requests, and eventually recovering to continue operations after 10 minutes?

I unfortunately have lost the data to check if the responses between 16:48:10 and 16:57:40 are error or success, but it is very likely that they are error responses from the proxy since node didn't have a care in the world.

Here are the flame charts seen in Chrome

- Before 16.47 hrs, 
  [image: Flame chart - normal operation (just before 16:47)]
- Around 16.47 hrs
  [image: Flame chart - around 16.47]
- A couple of minutes after 16.47 hrs
  [image: Flame chart - between 16.47 and 16.57]

Comment: Just curious, have you tried the app in the current version of Node? `4.5.0`

Comment: For "what could be the probable causes for the server to stay idle while being bombarded with client requests" the answer is: any of the things you didn't monitor at that moment. For example: everything is waiting for some lock somewhere (which eventually releases), ports are exhausted (but eventually released), slow GC, HD queue (if application involves any read/write to the disk), threads limit... Many, many things.

Comment: @Tracker1 : Yes, the app (eventually) hung with node 4.x and 5.x as well

Comment: @KirilS. quite right. I was wondering if there would be a known way to monitor things like event queue / closures in stack / ports opened within node. There's no doubt that some external factors play their part because the app hangs sometimes in a few minutes and other times after hours. However the infrastructure is shared by some java apps and they seem quite resilient to the issues

Comment: Are you running on OSX? This is a known problem on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons around this.

1. Server is not accepting the requests. Do you see drop in throughput after you reach the peak?
2. Have you checked the server logs to see if any exceptions are logged?
3. Try plotting trends of response time and throughput for your test duration.
4. You may want to see any IO bound operations in your code.
5. Check the processor queue length. You should see it building up if processes are not getting enough CPU.

Comment: Thanks @rachna, is there a way to monitor io-bound operations in nodejs? No particular exceptions in server logs.
I don't believe there was a peak in number of requests or any other parameter. The test was continuing in the manner for more than an hour when this occurred
Would you have a recommendation for checking queue length?

Comment: If you are running tests on linux based systems use sar command or check performance monitor in case windows. IO will also be covered by sar. Can you elaborate more on the JMeter results? may be upload graphs for response time and throughput?

Comment: The image I have posted at the beginning of the question is the response time chart. I sadly have not done a throughput analysis using a listener. Will try for that and update here.